# drag and drop into a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

So I have created a very short drag and drop program which works however there is a small glitch.

created a js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nz4m8zsh/) just to show you the issue I am facing

As you can see you are able to drop the cards into the dotted slots. the problem occurs when one moves the scroll bar of the div (that contain the slots). The cards do not seem to stick with the dotted slots. Now I am assuming it si due to absolute and relative position. I have tried changing  them but it creates more issues. i have also tried the offset method where by when the div is scrolled it calculates the offset of the slots and then uses those offsets to to position the cars. It doesn't work too well either. the code is given below.

```
$('#dropdiv').scroll(function() {
    var p = $( "#answerone" );
    var position = p.offset();
    console.log( "leftoffset: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
    var position3 = p.position();
    console.log( "leftpos: " + position3.left + ", top: " + position3.top );
    // ui.draggable.addClass( $(this).attr('id') );
    $("#card1").draggable( 'enable' );
    // $("#card1").droppable( 'enable' );
    // $("#card1").draggable.position( { of: $("#card1"), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    $("#card1").draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    var position2 =  $("#card1").offset();
    console.log( "left2222: " + position2.left + ", top: " + position2.top ); 
    var toppos=position.top-position2.top;
    console.log("div position.top  - "+position.top );
    console.log("element position2.top - "+position2.top);
    console.log("relativvtop - "+toppos);
    // console.log("scrollTop - "+$("#dropdiv")scrollTop());
    $("#card1").css( {postion:'absolute',top: toppos+'px'});
});
```

**edit1**: if i dont have a scrollable div then it works perfectly. but for some design reasons i need the scrollable div.

what am i doing wrong. how do i fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In `handleCardDrop()` I do not see where you append the dropped item to the container. Since it's not contained within the `<div>` but is basically floating, it retains it's absolute position when you scroll.

Comment: Looking at your fiddle, this is confirmed by inspecting the element after drop. It is still contained by `<div id="cardPile" style=" ">`.

Comment: @Twisty so basically i need to use a clone ? or do i need to ensure the positions of top and left are explicitly stated. the style is attached not by my code but by the drag and drop jquery ui function. so what should i do ?

Comment: neither of those. In your drop function, the dropped item should be appended to the container.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do some cleanup, but basically, when you drop the item, it never attaches to any of the content that is being scrolled.

For example, you could replace:

```
 ui.draggable.position({
   my: 'left top',
   at: 'left top',
   of: $(this)
 });
```

With:

```
 ui.draggable.css({
   top: "",
   left: ""
 }).appendTo($(this));
```

Your first piece of code simply sets the position of the item. When you scroll, that item remains in that position based on it's `top` and `left`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/x0fmgxaz/1/

This results in HTML of the following:

```
<div id="answerone" class="cardSlots answer ui-droppable" style="margin: 0 auto;display:block;float: none;" aria-disabled="false">
  <div id="card2" class="cardname ui-draggable answerone animated pulse" style="position: relative; z-index: 5;" aria-disabled="false">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.